# Error reading cscope connection after database update from cron

Tags: vim, cron, tags, cscope

I have a script setup which runs every night on all my projects and updates the cscope databases. The script basically deletes all existing cscope files (.files, .out etc) and generates new ones.

When the script is run via a cron job, it does complete successfully but I get error `E262: error reading cscope connection 0` within vim when I try to lookup a symbol. When I run the script manually, there's no problem.

The gist of the script is -

1. Delete existing `cscope.*` and `tags` files
2. Go through entire project and generate `cscope.files`
3. Build cscope database using `cscope -b -q`
4. Build tags database using `ctags --extra=+f -L cscope.files`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

I needed to source my bash_profile in the script so that all the environment variables were available to the script.

Adding `source ~/.bash_profile` to the top of the script fixed the issue.